# Opensource Network Management

Tags: networking

My network Admin asked me if I had heard of any opensource competitor to Ciscoworks and Solarwinds for Network Administration/Management.  We have a full implementation of Cacti and Nagios for monitoring, but I haven't really delved much into the realm of Cisco/Checkpoint/HP procurve management.  Anyone use anything that fits the bill?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest two options.  The first being more of a HP/Openview competitor that will scale very large but also has a lot of complextity to it.  That product is openNMS.  http://www.opennms.org.  The second tool which is the route we took is to use RANCID (horrible name but cool tool) http://www.shrubbery.net/rancid/.  It will diff your configs.  Therefore notifying you of any changes to network gear.  You can integrate it into other monitoring applications such as Zenoss http://www.zenoss.com/community/docs/zenoss-guide/2.2.4/ch35s02.html

But it really comes down to how you are managing your devices.  If you are a gui admin then it may be worth it to cough up the bucks for Ciscoworks or Solarwinds.

Comment: +1 for rancid; it makes ciscos manageable

Comment: Agreed.  Nothing keeps people honest like tracking changes automatically.  Tripwire is also great for this although for the really good stuff you have to pony up for their commercial product.  

The guys at Flickr did a great presentation @Velocity09 on how to have hyper velocity change but still ensure everyone stays honest.  Check it out.  http://velocityconference.blip.tv/file/2284377/

Answer (score 0):

I've recently started to use NeDi http://www.nedi.ch.  I haven't fully implemented all of the features ,but in my opinion, the ones I have used are at least on a par with CiscoWorks.  The web interface is also much faster.